# How to get Description of Youtube embeded videos in my asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, youtube, youtube-api, youtube.net-api

I am using the below code to get the Title and description of the youtube video embeded in my asp.net application. I am able to see the Title, but not description.

I use Atomfeed to do this...

Problem is i get the Description as **"Google.GData.Client.AtomTextConstruct"** for all my videos.

```
Private Function GetTitle(ByVal myFeed As AtomFeed) As String
    Dim strTitle As String = ""
    For Each entry As AtomEntry In myFeed.Entries
        strTitle = entry.Title.Text
    Next
    Return strTitle
End Function

Private Function GetDesc(ByVal myFeed As AtomFeed) As String
    Dim strDesc As String = ""
    For Each entry As AtomEntry In myFeed.Entries
        strDesc = entry.Summary.ToString()
    Next
    Return strDesc
End Function
```

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be entry.Summary.Text?
looks like Summary isnt a string. There should be something else inside summary that gives you string.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that when the XML from the atom feed is parsed, that the description is not handled. Take a look at this: http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/wiki/UnderstandingTheUnknown

> But what happens with things that are not understood? They end up as
>   an element of the ExtensionElements collection, that is a member of
>   all classes inherited from AtomBase, like AtomFeed, AtomEntry,
>   EventEntry etc...

So, what we can do is pull out the description from the extensionelement like this:

```
Dim query As New FeedQuery()
Dim service As New Service()
query.Uri = New Uri("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated")
Dim myFeed As AtomFeed = service.Query(query)
For Each entry In myFeed.Entries
    For Each obj As Object In entry.ExtensionElements
        If TypeOf obj Is XmlExtension Then
            Dim xel As XElement = XElement.Parse(TryCast(obj, XmlExtension).Node.OuterXml)
            If xel.Name = "{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}group" Then
                Dim descNode = xel.Descendants("{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}description").FirstOrDefault()
                If descNode IsNot Nothing Then
                    Console.WriteLine(descNode.Value)
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Also, the reason why you are getting "Google.GData.Client.AtomTextConstruct" is because Summary is an object of type Google.GData.Client.AtomTextConstruct, so doing  entry.Summary.ToString() is just giving you the default ToString() behavior. You would normally do Summary.Text, but this of course is blank because as I say above, it's not handled properly by the library.

Comment: How can i use this code for fetching the summary of Youtube video ?

Comment: You copy and paste this into your GetDesc function. The thing that didn't make sense to me was that you are looping through MULTIPLE videos and returning *one* description. But, in any case, if you try running this, you'll that descNode.Value contains the description of the video. See my edit for the complete code I had.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but, when i copy and paste your code, i get the following error : Type 'var' is not defined.

Comment: Ah right. I converted it from C#, forgot to fix that :). So, just remove the "as var" part. Fixed the code in my answer.

Comment: Type XmlExtension is not defined :(

Comment: Add `Imports Google.GData.Extensions`

Answer (score 0):

For youtube, I fetch the information for each video using the Google.GData.YouTube.

Something like this returns a lot of information from the video.

```
Dim yv As Google.YouTube.Video

url = New Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" & video.Custom)

r = New YouTubeRequest(New YouTubeRequestSettings("??", "??"))
yv = r.Retrieve(Of Video)(url)
```

Then it's possible to get the description with: yv.Description

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate ? How do i get the description of video here ? Thanks.